# : Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: php, string, exception, typeerror, offset

I get the following error
: Cannot access offset of type string on string

On this line

```
  <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/products_images/'.$row['prod_image'] ); ?>" alt="">
```

What can be the issue with the above line

This is the code...

```
<h2>PRODUCTS</h2>
    
<!-- Cart basket -->
<div class="cart-view">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('cart'); ?>" title="View Cart"><i class="icart"></i> (<?php echo ($this->cart->total_items() > 0)?$this->cart->total_items().' Items':'Empty'; ?>)</a>
</div>

<!-- List all products -->
<div class="row col-lg-12">
    <?php if(!empty($products)){ 
        foreach($products as $row){ ?>
        <div class="card col-lg-3">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/products_images/'.$row['prod_image'] ); ?>" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Price: <?php echo 'Ksh'.$row["price"].' Ksh'; ?></h6>
                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('products/addToCart/'.$row['id']); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } }else{ ?>
        <p>Product(s) not found...</p>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `$row` is a string, not an array.

Comment: do a simple `var_dump($products);` to see what in that array, then you will know whats in `$product` and what data type it is likely to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure `$row` is an array,is not string.Check `$products` variable in controller by debugging:

```
dd($products);
```